# IOS: scrollView with a paging random

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a scrollView and inside this scroll view I have 4 images. It's in paging enabled. But I want to do an IBAction that scroll these images random. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define numPages 4

CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * (arc4random() % (numPages - 1));
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be useful to you.
every time change the contentoffset

```
[scrollView contentOffset:CGSizeMake(totalscrollviewwidth,480];
```

And  find this [link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html) also